# How to boot repair disk through grub2

Tags: boot, grub2, 17.04

I dual-booted my laptop with Ubuntu 17.04. I decided I didn't want it anymore so I deleted the partition with Ubuntu installed and extended my windows partition. I restarted my computer and got this screen I can't get back to. I selected to boot into grub2 and now that's all my computer boots into. Doesn't boot from bootable USB drives or CDs. None of my commands are working. Always says file name expected or you need to load the kernel first. Ubuntu isn't installed but there has to be a way to boot from my recovery USB or simply into windows. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? Best to use the repair console on your Windows installer or repair flash drive (you did make that?). Boot-Repair cannot fix most Windows issues, but if not hibernated & BIOS it should offer to install a Windows like boot loader. If UEFI you should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. But then remove rest of grub.Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Comment: How do I tell if it's BIOS or UEFI? I mean, my boot menu key and my BIOS settings key did not work on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. install boot repair or windows recovery on a usb drive.
2. disable uefi boot.
3. boot from usb drive and repair.

Comment: I have the recovery on a USB but I can't boot into windows. The only thing that my computer boots into is grub2. Is there a way to disable UEFI in grub2?

Comment: i dont know about that, but you can make a windows recovery usb disk that will probably remove grub2, also the tool above is called boot repair not auto repair.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Need a recovery image on a flash drive. Removed the hard drive and upon boot up it brought me to the troubleshooting page that allowed me to reboot into the bios and change the boot sequence.